# How to optimize the sql query speed with calculation in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

In my table I have about 3 million records.
When i run this query it takes about 15-30 seconds to fetch count value

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `neighbours_count` FROM house 
WHERE 
    ( 6371 * 
          acos( 
              cos( radians( "48.70877900" ) ) * 
              cos( radians( `map_y` ) ) * cos( radians( `map_x` ) - 
              radians( "37.49893200" ) ) + sin( radians( "48.70877900" ) 
          ) 
          * sin( radians( `map_y` ) ) ) 
    ) <= 0.3
```

Query itself counts buildings within 300 meters of specific coordinates.
6371 is Earth radius, the rest in where part is formula to calculate proximity to the coordinates.

**Query explain**:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  house   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2442710     Using where
```

**Create statement**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `house` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `street_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `map_x` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `map_y` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `city_id` (`city_id`),
  KEY `street_id` (`street_id`),
  KEY `map_x` (`map_x`),
  KEY `map_y` (`map_y`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='map_y - latitude, map_x - longitude' AUTO_INCREMENT=2442769 ;
```

Please, give me an advice on how to optimize this query.

Comment: MySQL has some geospatial extensions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html  You will  need a "spatial index" for to improve this, otherwise it's always a full table scan doing the calculation 3,000,000 times

Comment: Could you do pre-processing to break the 3 million up into smaller groups and map those groups to coordinates?

Comment: Do you really need this data online? Make a new table with two columns `house_id` and `neighbours_count`; then update data once per hour/ per day.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for the hint, this extension is really what i needed.

Comment: Another solution:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to really optimize the query.  One method is to add additional conditions:

```
where (max_x between A and B and max_y between C and D) and
      . . .
```

The problem with this is that you cannot use an index on both `max_y` and `max_x`.  A variation would be to impose a grid 300 meters on each side and move each point to the nearest grid point.  This is a bit of a pain to implement (requiring triggers or something similar).  But you know that your condition means things are on adjacent grid points.  So, something like this:

```
where (grid_x, grid_y) in ((grid_A-1, grid_B), (grid_A-1, grid_B-1), (grid_A-1, grid_B+1),
                           (grid_A, grid_B), (grid_A, grid_B-1), (grid_A, grid_B+1),
                           (grid_A+1, grid_B), (grid_A+1, grid_B-1), (grid_A+1, grid_B+1)
                          ) and
       . . .
```

This can make use of an index on `grid_x, grid_y` -- I think.  If not, you can get the same effect by using `union all`.

Really, the best option are the [geospatial extensions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html).  GIS queries use different data structures from typical relational database data, which is why the extensions are needed.

Comment: Geospatial extensions is really what i missed here! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think the optimizer is too dumb to do the `WHERE (x,y) IN (...)` trick.  I tried a similar case, but it touched all rows.

Comment: @RickJames . . . You can force it by doing a `union all` query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - probably.  I did a quick test with one `WHERE (a,b) IN ((2,3))`; it worked ok.  OK = `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE `Handler%';` showed the number of rows returned, not the number of rows in the table (as before).

Comment: `UNION`, until very recently, suffers from _always_ creating a tmp table.  This is a minor overhead.  Also, `UNION ALL` would be better than `UNION DISTINCT`.

Comment: (You had me scared.  I thought you have come up with a better way than my complex, but efficient http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng )

Comment: `WHERE (hour, minute) < (11, 33)` has long been poorly optimized.  Maybe somebody will someday fix all the `(a,b)` comparisions.

Comment: BTW, I am testing on 5.6.13.

Answer (score 0):

It's a difficult answer. Maybe, I will try for:

- You have 3 *constants calls* in your select. 2 calls to `radians( "48.70877900" )` and 1 call to `radians( "37.49893200" )`). I would try to change these calls for constants values if it's possible.
- You cand add more conditions in your SELECT, for example, removing map_x or map_y so far from origin, like `abs( map_x - origin_x ) > MAX_X_DISTANCE`

I hope you will find it helpful

PD: Try with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `neighbours_count` 
FROM 
    (SELECT radians( "48.70877900" ) rX, radians( "37.49893200" ) rY FROM DUAL) Rad,
    house 
WHERE 
    ( 6371 * 
          acos( 
              cos( Rad.rX ) * 
              cos( radians( `map_y` ) ) * cos( radians( `map_x` ) - 
              Rad.rY ) + sin( Rad.rX 
          ) 
          * sin( radians( `map_y` ) ) ) 
    ) <= 0.3
```